# How to remove NewItemPlaceholder at TreeView wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, treeview

I bind ObservableCollection to ListView and I get {NewItemPlaceholder} line at the end. How can I hide or remove that line?

[image]

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataToDisplay}">
```

Collection looks like:

```
ObservableCollection<MyElement> MyDataToDisplay
```

Comment: You might be having a default constructor in MyElement class. Remove that constructor and NewItemPlaceHolder will not be shown.

Comment: Yes there is a constructor on a base class of element class MyElement, but I can't remove it. Could I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set an ItemTemplate in the XAML for the ListView (in my example a TreeView, where the same failure happens), and bind it to a filter converter. This could look like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter}}"/>                  
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now you have to add a Filter-Converter-Class like this:

```
class IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter : IValueConverter {
    public static readonly IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter Instance = new IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value != null && value.ToString() == "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to map this Filterclass a static resource in your XAML with something like this:

```
<converter:IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter x:Key="IgnoreNewItemPlaceholderConverter"/>
```

This is caused by a DataGrid  beeing bound to the same datasource, that is not "IsReadOnly=True" (writable). If this still fits your requirements, you can also try to make the DataGrid readonly or to bind to a different datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but just came across this problem. I have a treeview & datagrid bound to the same datasource; however making the datagrid IsReadOnly=true wasn't an option because I need to be able to edit the datagrid. I found that setting CanUserAddRows=false fixed the issue and still allowed me to edit the Datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly I solved my problem. The problem was that on the same window I had a DataGrid binded to the same collection. I think that I had to make the DataGrid readonly to eliminate that row in the TreeView. However the DataGrid was just for testing purpose so the problem is gone.

Comment: Great! Just a note: Another way to eliminate the NewItemPlaceHolder is to create a DataTemplate with a Label inside and apply that template as ItemTemplate to TreeView. If you needed to have a DataGrid, then this would be the solution.

Comment: Thanks it will help me in future

Comment: Look at my example for this. I used a ContentControl instead of a Label.

Answer (score 1):

Like alot of people, I had the same issues  but after some thinking, it occured to me that I could just create a bool property in the ViewModel and bind it to the DataGrid CanUserAddRows Property like below. Then I can make the property true or false as needed:

```
private bool _canUserAddRows;
    public bool CanUserAddRows
    {
        get { return _canUserAddRows; }
        set
        {
            _canUserAddRows = value;

            NotifyPropertyChanged("CanUserAddRows");
        }
    }
```

```css
<--!--DataGrid property --!-->
CanUserAddRows="{Binding CanUserAddRows,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This is easier and works very well. Hope it helps you.